# Number of internal nodes in a Decision Tree

Tags: machine-learning, classification

The number of internal nodes in a decision tree is not equal to the size (n) of the input feature vector? It is always less than n or the upper bound on the number of decision nodes will be n? How to draw a relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a decision tree is a process where the algorithm picks the first feature to split on $i_1$ from the set of features $n$ that it can split on $i_1={1,...,n}$.

After splitting, the algorithm has to decide whether to stop building the tree or split on another feature $i_2={1,...,n} \ $ AND $i_2 \ne i_1$, and the process repeats where the algorithm keeps deciding whether to stop or split on a new feature $i_3={1,...,n} \ $ AND $i_3 \ne i_2 \ne i_1$. This keeps going until the algorithm decided to stop building the tree or it has split on all $n$ features and there exists no feature $i_{n+1}={1,...,n}$ that can satisfy the condition $i_{n+1} \ne i_n \ne ... \ne i_2 \ne i_1$. Thus there are no more features to split on.

Thus the maximum number of nodes has to be less than or equal to the size ($n$) of the input feature.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can we say that for an unpruned tree the number of internal nodes is equal to n?

Comment: That depends on what algorithm you use to build the tree? In some algorithms yes, but in others (ones with early stopping for example) then no.
Unless you consider early stopping to be theoretically equivalent to pruning, then I guess the answer to your question would be yes.
It all depends on the algorithm and how you define things, but I would say no (due to the early stopping example).